# Symfony Doctrine order oneToMany by specific order

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I use Symfony 4, and I have a OneToMany relation. I want to order this relation by a specific order. For now, I order only by ASC :

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Ingredients", mappedBy="product", fetch="EAGER")
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"family" = "ASC"})
 */
private $ingredients;
```

It works perfectly.

Now I would like to order by a specific order : "vegetables", "fruits" then "meat".

I tried :

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Ingredients", mappedBy="product", fetch="EAGER")
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"family" = "vegetables, fruits, meat"})
 */
private $ingredients;
```

Which is of course doesn't work. Still trying, but is there an easy way to achieve it ?

Comment: I don't think that this can be accomplished with the orderBy annotation.

Comment: And it should not be for performance reasons. Use a repository method for that purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref_orderby

> The DQL Snippet in OrderBy is only allowed to consist of unqualified, unquoted field names and of an optional ASC/DESC positional statement. Multiple Fields are separated by a comma (,). The referenced field names have to exist on the targetEntity class of the @ManyToMany or @OneToMany annotation.

However if you use DQL you should be able to accomplish this with something like:

```
$qb = $em->getRepository(Ingredients::class)->createQueryBuilder('i');
$results = $qb->orderBy('FIELD(family,vegetables,fruits,meat)')
              ->getQuery()
              ->getResults();
```

** I havent tested this code **